# Match all words of list in string using regex or any other way

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python script where i have to match all words given in list with the string. The list could be as long as possible. But i found operations that will match any of the character but couldn't find operation to match all words in list. For example

```
 s = "This is a sample string"
 list = ["is", "sample"]

// any operation such that re.search(r'',s) return correct result
// I want that regular expression or approach to do it.
```

Comment: Which words do you want to select ?

Comment: All words in list

Comment: @danish, it's not clear from text of your question, what "all words" means for you.

Comment: You could iterate over the list with something like `/\bword\b/g`. You can add the matches to an array.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: By the way, isn't is useless to make list of words you .. already have in list?

Comment: I think he wants a list of all the words that are present in both his string and his list.

Comment: What do you expect the results to be in your example? Also, is 'ring' a word that would be in you sample string or wouldn't be because it is only part of the word 'string'?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import re

string = "This is a sample string"
lst = ["is", "sample"]

for item in lst:
    rx = re.compile(r"\b{}\b".format(item))
    if rx.search(string):
        print("'{}' is in the string".format(item))
```

This yields

```
'is' is in the string
'sample' is in the string
```